# How to split a string at a specific "/" when it hold many "/"-characters

Tags: c#

For example:

I'm havning this string:

```
/child1/child2/child3/
```

And the result I want is:

```
/child1/child2/
```

Note that every child can be of different lenght. For example:

```
/someString/anotherString/andOneMore/
```

The string can also just be (in this last case I need to keep the "/" as it is):

```
/
```

Comment: And how you are trying to split it now?

Comment: `String.Split()`, then `String.Join()` the parts you want would be one way to do it

Comment: What's the criteria to splitting?

Comment: "... or something" Can you be more detailed than that?

Comment: ElGavilan: If have this:
`/child1/child2/child3/`
And do this:
`string[] SplittedUrl = FullUrl.Split('/');`
Then I want my result to be like this:
`/child1/child2/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will handle `/` string separately:

```
private string TruncatePath(string path)
{
    if (path == "/")
        return path;

    var parts = path.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return String.Format("/{0}/", String.Join("/", parts.Take(2)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I cant use the part:
    input.Split. Getting an error there.

Comment: the part "input" in my case is a string

Comment: @user3228992 `Split` is a method of string class.

Comment: Yes I know but I cant use it, don't know why. Is it because it is a property: `public string input {get; set;}` ?

Comment: @user3228992 do you see any members of string when you write `input.`?

Comment: Sorry I was messing things up! I'm gonna try your solution again now :)

Comment: Was trying it out now. But If I'm having this string as path: `/child1/child2/child3/` The output i s still the same. The result I want is: `/child1/child2/`

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for replace not split. Using regex we match the first two items and simply output them.

```
var pattern = @"(/[^/]+/)[^/]+/([^/]+/)";

Regex.Replace("/child1/child2/child3/",
              pattern,
              "$1$2"); // result `/child1/child3/`

Regex.Replace("/someString/anotherString/andOneMore/",
              pattern,
              "$1$2"); // result `/someString/andOneMore/`

Regex.Replace("/",
              pattern,
              "$1$2"); // result `/`
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to split a string "at" a given slash?

```
int splitAt = 3;
var parts = "dsf/df/ss/sdfsfd/fsdfsd".Split('/').ToList();
var headParts = parts.Take(splitAt);
var tailParts = parts.Skip(splitAt);
var head = String.Join("/",headParts.ToArray()).Dump();
var tail = String.Join("/",tailParts.ToArray()).Dump();
```